# How to upgrade OpenSSH on Centos

Tags: centos, openssh

I'm using Centos 6 and openssh 5.3 and I want to upgrade to openssh 7 but I don't know how.
I have tried using google but have not found out how.

Answer (score 0):

To update OpenSSH to the latest version that the CentOS repository has, run the following command:

`su -c 'yum update'`

This will perform a full system update.  At the prompt (from the `su` part), enter your *root* password

For future reference, you may find the [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) to also be of use.

Answer (score 0):

```
yum groupinstall "Development Tools"

yum install zlib-devel openssl-devel

cp /etc/ssh/sshd_config  /etc/ssh/sshd_config

wget -c  https://cdn.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/OpenSSH/portable/openssh-9.0p1.tar.gz

tar -xzf  openssh-9.0p1.tar.gz

cd openssh-9.0p1/

yum install pam-devel libselinux-devel

./configure  --with-pam --with-selinux --with-privsep-path=/var/lib/sshd/ --sysconfdir=/etc/ssh

make

make install

ssh -V
```